# Hashing a non-reduced fraction

Tags: hash, fractions

How can I write a hash function that works for a fraction of arbitrary size, and is equal for different fractions that reduce the same way?

- I tried converting it to a `double` but two fractions that are reduced to the same number may be off by the slightest amount and thus have completely different hashes.
- GCD would make useless the O(1) time of a hash function, and making all fractions always recuced would slow my program significantly.

Comment: Uh, you *have* to reduce your fractions to find a hash function that maps equivalent fractions to the same value. There is no sensible way around this.

Comment: You don't *have* to reduce the fraction. You can make the hash function do it, for example by making the hash function map the fraction to a finite field. a/b = ab' mod p where b' is the [multiplicative inverse of b mod p](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse).